# How to count reflows in the browser via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, reflow

I want to write an unit test for a JavaScript function and measure how often a function triggered a reflow in the browser. Given the following example:

```js
// Bad example
function foo(elements) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].className = 'w' + elements[i].offsetWidth;
    }
}
// Good example
function foo(elements) {
    var widths = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        widths[i] = elements[i].offsetWidth;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].className = 'w' + widths[i];
    }
}
```

The unit test should fail for the first example because it triggers a reflow for every element, but should pass for the second example because it doesn’t trigger a reflow.

The only thing that comes near to what I want is [`mozPaintCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/mozPaintCount), but it only increments for every paint and not for every reflow. I would need something like `mozReflowCount` or `mozRecalculateStyleCount`, but I didn’t find anything likely in any browser. If such a property exists the unit test could look like this:

```js
// mozReflowCount doesn’t exist, such a property is what I’m looking for
var reflowCountBefore = window.mozReflowCount;
foo(document.querySelectorAll('*'));
if (reflowCountBefore === window.mozReflowCount) {
    // passed
}
else {
    // failed
}
```

I know that I can take a look at the developer tools of the browser to check manually how many reflows or “forced synchronous layouts” were triggered, but I don’t know how to access that data from within a JavaScript unit test.

**Q: How do I count reflows in the browser via JavaScript?**

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to use the MutationObserver: [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

The example on that page gives a pretty good rundown as to how you could implement this:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: A MutationObserver would only tell me what changes happened to the DOM, but not if a reflow happened or not. Both `foo()` functions in my example above would trigger the same DOM modifications and therefore the same observer mutations.